# How does DeGray's Pilebunker chip work when trashing Gems of size 2+?

Tags: puzzle-strike

In Puzzle Strike, the "Pilebunker" chip says:

> Opponents reveal their hands, trash their largest [Gem chip], then <strike>you</strike> gain that many [1 Gems chip]s.

<strike>How does this work when trashing 2-Gem, 3-Gem, or 4-Gem chips?</strike>

More specific example: if it's a 2 player game and I play Pilebunker, and my opponent trashes a 4-Gem chip, which do i gain?

- 1 1-Gem chip, or
- 4 1-Gem chips?

**Edit:** As per @lilserf's answer, I had misread the tile completely.  A full list of tiles can be found [here](http://www.sirlingames.com/pages/puzzle-strike-chip-images). And here is what the chip *actually* says:

[image: Pilebunker: +1 Chip. Opponents reveal their hands, trash their largest (Gem chip), then gain that many (1 Gems chip)s.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't gain anything!

Pilebunker's actual wording is:

> Opponents reveal their hands, trash their largest [Gem chip], **then gain** that many [1 Gem chip]s.

Note that it's "then gain", not "then you gain" - each opponent gains the 1-Gems. 
Pilebunker effectively splits their biggest gem in their hand into 1-gems, diluting their deck.

Comment: Wow, if that's true then both me *and* a friend both misread the tile completely.

Comment: I too played this one wrong today. We went back and forth discussing possible interpretations, and decided that just breaking up the opponents' gems didn't seem powerful enough, and that it must be conferring some transfer of benefit to the holder. Of course, I wound up losing that game anyway -- perhaps for having too many 1-gems in *my own* hand.

Comment: Yeah, breaking the opponent's gems actually turns out to be INCREDIBLY annoying and plenty powerful, though it doesn't seem so at first.